# Textarea-N with recount and disable button function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, textarea

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.comment').bind("blur focus keydown keypress keyup", function(){recountss();});
    $('input.comment_button').attr('disabled','disabled');

    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        tweet();
    });

});

function recountss()
{
    var maxlen=280;
    var current = maxlen-$('.comment').val().length;
    $('.counters').html(current);

    if(current<0 || current==maxlen)
    {
        $('.counters').css('color','#D40D12');
                 $('input.comment_button').attr('disabled','disabled').addClass('inact');
    }
    else if (!$.trim($(".comment").val())) 
    {
            $('input.comment_button').attr('disabled','disabled').addClass('inact');
    }
    else
            $('input.comment_button').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('inact');


    if(current<10)
    {
        $('.counters').css('color','#D40D12');

    } 
    else if(current<20)
    {
        $('.counters').css('color','#5C0002');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.counters').css('color','#C0C0C0');
    }
```

---

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form">
<textarea name="comment" class="comment" id="ctextarea<?php echo $msg_id;?>" ></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="<?php echo $uid; ?>"/>
<div class="p"></div>
    <input type="submit"  value="Comment"  id="<?php echo $msg_id;?>" class="comment_button"/>
    <span class="counters">
        280
    </span>
</form>
```

I using jquery.
I have more than 1 textarea, if I type in textarea-1, it work, button disabled if no any text and recount working good.

But if I type in textarea-2, textarea-3, textarea-N, it can't work.
So how can I do to make all works ?

Thank you.

Comment: type in where exactly? i dont understand your question

Comment: Is each `<textarea>` => `maxlen<=280`? Or is `textarea-1`+`textarea-2`+.. => `maxlen<=280`?

Comment: What I want is just count input textarea. But now I have more than 1 textarea, see. And the problem coming in textarea-2 and textarea-N. It can't count.

Comment: Are all the `<textarea>`'s in the same form - `<form><texarea-1><textarea-2>...</form>` or are they in their own form -`<form><texarea-1></form><form><textarea-2>...</form><form>...</form>`?

Comment: @Sean all the textarea is in the same form, that makes it different is the textarea ID

Comment: So does  `<textarea-1>` => `maxlen=280`, `<textarea-2>` => `maxlen=280`, ...? Or is `<textarea-1>`+`<textarea-2>`+`..` => `maxlen=280`

Comment: correct Mr. @Sean, so how can set that ?

Comment: <textarea-1> => maxlen=280, <textarea-2> => maxlen=280

Answer (score 0):

If each `<textarea>` has its own `maxlen=280`, it would be better to change from using `class` - `$('.comment')` to `id` - `$('#ctextarea-'+i)` on all elements - `<textarea>`, `<button>`, `<span>`, etc.

This is untested, but should help point you in the right direction.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var i=1;
    var numtextarea = 1; 
    $('#form').find('textarea').each(function(){numtextarea++;} //find number of <textarea>'s
    while(i<numtextarea){ // loop through each <textarea>
    $('#ctextarea-'+i).bind("blur focus keydown keypress keyup", function(){recountss(i);});
    $('#comment_button-'i).attr('disabled','disabled'); 
    }
    });
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        tweet();
    });
});

    function recountss(i)
    {
        var maxlen=280;
        var current = maxlen-$('#ctextarea-'+i).val().length;
        $('#counters-'+i).html(current);
        if(current<0 || current==maxlen)
        {
            $('#counters-'+i).css('color','#D40D12');
            $('#comment_button-'+i).attr('disabled','disabled').addClass('inact');
        }
        else if (!$.trim($("#ctextarea-'+i).val())) {
            $('#comment_button-'+i).attr('disabled','disabled').addClass('inact');
        }
        else
            $('#comment_button-'+i).removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('inact');


        if(current<10)
            $('#counters-'+i).css('color','#D40D12');

        else if(current<20)
            $('#counters-'+i).css('color','#5C0002');

        else
            $('#counters-'+i).css('color','#C0C0C0');
    }
```

And your form should look like -

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form">

<textarea name="comment" class="comment" id="ctextarea-1" ></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="1"/>
<div class="p"></div>
<input type="submit"  value="Comment"  id="comment_button-1" class="comment_button"/>
<span id="counters-1">
    280
</span>

<textarea name="comment" class="comment" id="ctextarea-2" ></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="2"/>
<div class="p"></div>
<input type="submit"  value="Comment"  id="comment_button-2" class="comment_button"/>
<span id="counters-2">
    280
</span>

...

<textarea name="comment" class="comment" id="ctextarea-N" ></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="N"/>
<div class="p"></div>
<input type="submit"  value="Comment"  id="comment_button-N" class="comment_button"/>
<span id="counters-N">
    280
</span>

</form>
```